# How to link MySQL to html

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, sql, gedit

I am trying to create a website using html in gedit, and i need to be able to log in or register at the homepage which then takes the user to their page on the website, where they are able to input a message, i need the message to go into a database, and to be able to show it at another page on the website. I am confused on how to link html to MySQL when information is created using a form.
I would appreciate if anyone can help me please,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For dynamic application you need to choose language available in programming. You can't do it in just a static web application like with HTML pages only.

Comment: HTML5 has come with the solution ,, so you can check out there documentation

Comment: @Sam Arul Raj — There are various client side SQL solutions. None of them are in HTML 5 (they just appeared at about the same time). None of them are MySQL. None of them are any good for a login system (because you can't have a shared user database stored in the *browser*!).

Comment: @Quentin thanks a lot , i realized

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some server side language to do this. The way it would work is the form would have a URL associated with it for where it would submit the data to. This page should be a PHP script or ASP page or something like that.

Once you have a PHP script you can connect to the database and insert in the records as required with the data.

Here is a good resource if you're not familiar with this:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: i have been using that website, but i really dont understand how to set this whole thing up. I have installed MySQL, and gedit, do i need anything more for the sql side of it?

Comment: For the sql side no, but that article walks you through the PHP side, which is important and cannot be avoided. PHP (or some server side language) is needed to link the HTML with the MySQL server.

Comment: That is a *dreadful* site. There is a huge SQL Injection vulnerability in the code they teach you to write on that page.

Comment: Unfortunately most php tutorials teach you to do things that way. I'd recommend using PDO for all database queries where some parameters are involved to be truely safe from injection attacks.

Comment: I am really sorry to keep asking, but is there any way you can explain this abit clearer for me please. I looked at the link you showed me which says to download PHP and Apache, i thought PHP was a language? do i still need to download it? and I tried to download Apache but it doesnt open, is there an alternative or any way you can help me please? thank you

Comment: You would probably be better off using something like Xampp. This is a standalone web server with PHP already built in. PHP is an interpreter, so you normally need to install it in addition to Apache. Find XAMPP here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/

Comment: PHP is a language but you need an interpretor for it.

Comment: so do i write the php language in gedit? and have xampp running as the server? i am really confused im sorry, i am used to linking the mysql to android applications, but have no idea when it came to linking to a website

Comment: You can write php in gedit, it's just text. You need to put the php files you write into "C:\xampp\htdocs\" so that when you go to "http://localhost" in your browser, it can load them.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some sort of server side language like PHP for example. With PHP you can connect to a DB and insert data according to forms that you submit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer to your query comes very late (6 years too late) but for the sake of all the newbies out there who googled and reached this page in search of the same question, here's a good response:

## Tutorial to use an HTML web-page to interact with a MySQL database using PHP

The tutorial takes you through establishing a mysql connection using php on a web page, connecting to a mysql table and retrieving the results and displaying them back on the web page.

This tutorial uses the PHP MySQL commands:

1. mysqli_connect
2. mysqli_query
3. mysqli_fetch_array
4. mysqli_close

### The Plan

- make the connection and select the database
- perform the query on the table
- print out the data
- close the connection

### First Up – Connecting to a MySQL database

You need your MySQL server address (if the database is on the same server as the web server it will most likely be localhost or 127.0.0.1), username, password and  database name. Create a filenamehere.php file and open and close the php code with tags before the html, you can put regular html after it. Open the file in a browser and you should see nothing apart from the title tag, if you see the error the username/password or database name may be wrong.

PHP will require that mysqli is enabled (it is on most PHP set ups).

```
<?php
//Step1
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database_name')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>

<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

The variable **$db** is created and assigned as the connection string, it will be used in future steps. If there is a failure then an error message will be displayed on the page. If it is successful you will see PHP connect to MySQL.

### Performing a database query

The mysql query is actually performed in the body of the html page, so additional php opening and closing tags will be required. For the query we are going to specify a read of all fields from a given table. The  $query variable selects all rows in the table. You just need to use your table name.

```
<?php
//Step1
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','database_name')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>

<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>

<?php
//Step2
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database..');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Again the returned page in the browser should be blank and error free, if you do receive the error – ***‘Error querying database..’*** check the table name is correct.
Put the data on the page

Here we are making a ***$result*** variable which stores the query we just made above, now we just need to go through all the rows of that query which we need ***mysqli_fetch_array*** which stores the rows in an array, so now we are storing the $result in mysqli_fetch_array and passing that into a variable called ***$row***.

The $row now can be output in a **while** loop, here the rows of data will be echoed and displayed on the page to when there is no longer any rows of data left, this example uses 4 fields in the table **first_name**, **last_name**, **email** and **city**.

```
<?php
//Step1
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','database_name')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>

<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>

  <?php
  //Step2
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
  mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ': ' . $row['email'] . ' ' . $row['city'] .'<br />';}
  ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

Here you should see the all data as output from your table.

### Closing off the connection

Closing the connection will require another set off opening and closing php tags after the closing html tag. It is good practice to close the database connection when the querying is done.

```
<?php
//Step1
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','database_name')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>

<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>

  <?php
  //Step2
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
  mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

  //Step3
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ': ' . $row['email'] . ' ' . $row['city'] .'<br />';}
  //Step 4
  mysqli_close($db);
  ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

Database connections should always be closed off. You do not need to keep the connection variable $db after the initial connection but is considered best practice.

Comment: Your intentions are good (I too learned to code with exactly this type of code!), but I'm not sure tutorials should be posted here. Besides, the question does not mention PHP, so it would be nice to at least add some hints on what is php and how it should be installed, etc. Try to make your answers short and objective and point to a link with more information, if needed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use PHP, try WAMP it has PHP, MYSQL databse

here is a simple form
Your database table test

```
create table test
(id int not null auto_increment primary key,
firstname nvarchar(20)
);
```

Then using Server side PHP

```
//tst.php file
<?php
$connect=mysql_connect('hostname','username','password');
mysql_select_db('databaseName');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $firstname=mysql_real_escape_strings($_POST['firstname']);
   $ret=mysql_query("insert into test(firstname) values ('$firstname')")
}
?>
<html>
   <head> </head>
   <body>
   <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="firstname" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit" />
   </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```